# Grails 4 with multiple dataSource not works for me

Tags: grails

I have this configuration in my application.yml

```
---
hibernate:
  cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: false
    use_query_cache: false
dataSource:
  pooled: true
  jmxExport: true
  driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
  username: root
  password: ""

environments:
  development:
    pathFiles: C://pw-inventory
    dataSource:
      dbCreate: update
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory_dev
    dataSources:
      two:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pw-security
```

And I have this class

```
class Test {

  String a
  String b

  static mapping = {
    datasource('two')
  }

}
```

The table for test is created in two dataSource, but when I try to use `Test.list([:])` and `Test.two.list([:])` but I get this error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

Comment: I think that is because there is no session found in the current thread.  Can you express from what context you are invoking these queries?